# Passing two arguments to the .map callback function

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

R stands for the Ramda.js library, similar to the Underscore.js

```
var test = [
  {p1: 1}
];

var get = R.curry(function(prop, obj) { return obj[prop]; });
console.log(R.map(get('p1'), test));
```

what i know about the R.map callback that it takes only one argument but here we passed two arguments **prop, obj** and it's working ?

> we didn't use obj so it should be undefined --> return undefined[prop]
>   right ?

this code prove that map callback takes only one argument

```
var test = [
  {p1: 1}
];

function fn(arg1, arg2) {
  return arg1 + ' ' + arg2 + '\n';
}

console.log(R.map(fn, test));
```

the result is

```
["[object Object] undefined"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works because `get` is a curried function. This means that `get('p1')` returns a function which takes one argument. In this case, it returns a function like this:

```
function(obj) { return obj['p1']; });
```

This allows it to be passed to the `R.map` function.

To understand currying, the wikipedia article is rather stellar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: Ohh, wow that's so so good, functional programming is so powerful
man i really appreciate your help.